# Docker volume persistent

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have two questions about docker volume.

First : When I run my docker with a volume which it creates with `docker volume create` or with docker-compose, new files on the default directory are not appended to the volume. I give an example :

```
docker volume create testdock-logs

docker run -d -p 80:80 --name testdock --restart=on-failure -v testdock-logs:/var/www/logs testdock:latest -s
```

After that when I create a new file or directory on `/var/www/logs` and build my image testdocker, I don't find my new file on the volume.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to split your question into two separate questions. If possible provide an example that someone else can execute that shows the issue more clearly.

Comment: I split my question and let an example for test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker doesn't replace files in a volume with those in a modified image. Doing so would defeat the purpose of a volume, this is the one persistent location you have to store data that isn't reverted back to the image state when the container is recreated.

If you need the files from your image instead of the files in your volume, then reconsider whether you actually need a volume.

Comment: Thank for you answer i will change my method.