# docker persistent storage via volume

Tags: docker, storage, persistence, docker-volume

All that read are saying that we can create docker persistent storage via the `VOLUME` control, e.g., [here](https://dev.to/jibinliu/how-to-persist-data-in-docker-container-2m72) and [here](https://thenewstack.io/methods-dealing-container-storage/).

However, I have the following in my `Dockerfile`:

```
VOLUME      ["/home", "/root"]
```

but nothing was kept in there (I tried `touch abc`, and when I exit and get back in again the file is not there).

I see that the [official usage](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/apt-cacher-ng/) has no other special controls or treatments, yet it can provide persistent storage, even the `apt-cacher-ng` service container is stopped.

How is that possible? I've checked out the following but still don't have a clue:

- [Docker volume persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562966/docker-volume-persistent)
- [Persistent Docker volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766998/persistent-docker-volume)
- [Docker volume vs. persistent volume on official Docker beginner tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476138/)

In conclusion, as explained [here](https://thenewstack.io/methods-dealing-container-storage/):

> The first mechanism will create an implicit storage sandbox for the container that requested host-based persistence. ... The key thing to understand is that the data stored in the sandbox is not available to other containers, except the one that requested it.

How can I make persistent storage works? Why my changes are wiped each time, while the `apt-cacher-ng` service container can maintain its persistent storage even it is stopped and restarted? 
What is the *"other special controls or treatments"* that I failed to see here?

Explain with plain simple `Dockerfile` (not `docker-compose.yml` ) please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the VOLUME instruction creates an external storage when the docker run is used without the "mount" option for that specific folder. In other words, every time you create a container for that image, docker will create a new volume with a random label but since you're not giving those volumes a name, the new containers cannot re-use the existing generated volumes.

e.g.

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN mkdir /myvol
RUN echo "hello world" > /myvol/greeting
VOLUME /myvol
```

Given this Dockerfile, if you simply build and run this docker image using the following commands:

```
echo "There are currently $(docker volume ls | wc -l) volumes"

docker build -t my_volume_test:latest .
docker run --name another_test my_volume_test:latest

echo "There are currently $(docker volume ls | wc -l) volumes"
```

you'll see that the amount of volumes present on your machine has increased. That container is now using a volume to store the data but that specific volume does not have a name or label so it's only bound to that specific container. If you delete and recreate that container, docker will generate a new volume with a random name unless you manage to mount the volume you've created earlier.

If you want to make it easy, I suggest to first create the volume and mount it then. e.g.

```sh
docker rm -f another_test
docker volume create my-vol

docker run \
    --name another_test \
    --mount source=my-vol,target=/myvol \
    my_volume_test:latest

# alternative
docker rm -f another_test
docker run \
    --name another_test \
    -v my-vol:/myvol \
    my_volume_test:latest
```

In this case you can create and remove as many containers you want but they'll all use the same volume.

check the [VOLUME reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) and [Use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Stefano, one more quick question. So the conclusion is that I have to mount volume into the docker each time I invoke it. Now, the question is, in such case, what different it will make then, to define such mount volume with VOLUME in the Dockerfile? Not defining/declaring it would still work, right? thx

Comment: yep, it keeps working. But as I wrote if you destroy that container and create a new one, you have to search what was the name of the automatically generated volume. It might not be an easy feat.

Comment: I meant, as long as I'm using `-v my-vol:/myvol` each time when invoking docker, defining/declaring `VOLUME /myvol` in the Dockerfile doesn't really matter and has no difference at all in such case, right? I.e. it is therefore better not to defining/declaring `VOLUME /myvol` in the Dockerfile because it'll create extra volume on the host each time not using volume mapping, and they are not reusable and not easy to manage, right?

Comment: well, it depends on what you're trying to do but generally if you don't need docker to create volumes automatically, then yes better not use the VOLUME instruction.